# Multivariable Function Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I would like to take a derivative, but it is not a very common one.

I have two equations:
$$f = \log \Big[ \frac{N!}{y! (N-y)!}q^y(1-q)^{(N-y)}\Big]$$

$$Nq = \beta^T x$$

where $\beta$ and $x$ are vectors, the rest are scalars.

I would like to calculate $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta}$$

Of course if I could simply plug the second formula to the first, it would have been easier.

How would one apply chain rule in this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the logarithm

$$
f= \log \frac{N!}{y!(N-y)!}+y\log q + (N-y)\log(1-q)
$$

Taking the derivative of each term is now easier

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial q} = \frac{y - Nq}{q(1-q)}
$$

Finally

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial {\bf \beta}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial {\bf \beta}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial q}\frac{{\bf x}}{N} = \frac{y - Nq}{q(1-q)}\frac{{\bf x}}{N}
$$

Comment: Great. I think just one $1/N$ missing from $\partial q / \partial \beta$.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc You're right. Already fixed it!